NextJS: Module not found: Package path ./llms/hf is not exported from package
Impossible to import langchain/llms/hf.
I am using
yarn add @langchain/community @langchain/core @huggingface/inference@2
No error triggered when doing yarn install or yarn add the above libraries.
Package JSON
  "name": "nextjs-tailwindcss-chatgpt-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@huggingface/inference": "2",
    "@langchain/community": "^0.3.2",
    "@langchain/core": "^0.3.2",
    "@langchain/openai": "^0.3.2",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "langchain": "^0.3.2",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.46.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.22",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.38.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1"
  }
}

Code
./src/pages/api/hf.ts
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { HuggingFaceInference } from "langchain/llms/hf";

// Get your environment variables
dotenv.config();

// Hugging Face Inference model setup with the dedicated endpoint
const hfModel = new HuggingFaceInference({
  endpointUrl: process.env.HUGGINGFACE_INFERENCE_ENDPOINT, // Use the env variable for the endpoint URL
  apiKey: process.env.HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_KEY,             // Hugging Face API key for authorization
  temperature: 0.5,                                       // Configure as per your needs
});

// Define a custom message type if needed
interface Message {
  role: string;
  content: string;
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
    return;
  }

  const body = req.body;
  const messages = (body?.messages || []) as Message[];

  try {
    // Add a system message prompt to guide the model
    const systemMessage: Message = {
      role: "system",
      content: "You are a helpful assistant. Respond to the user with clarity and insight.",
    };

    // Combine system and user messages for context
    const messageHistory = [systemMessage, ...messages]
      .map((message) => message.content)
      .join("\n"); // Convert the messages array into a single prompt string

    // Call the Hugging Face model with the combined message history
    const response = await hfModel.invoke({
      prompt: messageHistory, // Send the entire message history
    });

    // Extract the response content
    const responseMessage = response?.generated_text?.trim();

    if (!responseMessage) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: "Unable to get a response from Hugging Face. Please try again.",
      });
      return;
    }

    // Return the response message
    res.status(200).json({ message: responseMessage });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: "An error occurred while invoking Hugging Face. Please try again.",
    });
  }
}

How to import huggingface on langchain:
https://js.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/huggingface_inference/
Error Message:
./src/pages/api/hf.ts:3:0
Module not found: Package path ./llms/hf is not exported from package /Users/XXXXX/Documents/XXXX/playground/nextjs-tailwindcss-chatgpt-clone/node_modules/langchain (see exports field in /Users/XXXX/Documents/XXXX/playground/nextjs-tailwindcss-chatgpt-clone/node_modules/langchain/package.json)
  1 | import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
  2 | import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
**> 3 | import { HuggingFaceInference } from "langchain/llms/hf";**
  4 | 
  5 | // Get your environment variables
  6 | dotenv.config();

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

